# How do I prevent Ace Editor from auto-completing as I type?

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, ace-editor

I want the suggestion to show up only when I use `Cntrl-Spacebar`. Their documentation is a bit lacking.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set these following variables :

```
enableBasicAutocompletion:true
enableLiveAutocompletion:false
```

for achieving auto-completion only on pressing `Cntrl - Spacebar`.

Check this snippet for live demo :

```js
  var langTools = ace.require("ace/ext/language_tools");
  var editor = ace.edit("editor");
  editor.setOptions({
    enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
    enableLiveAutocompletion: false
  });
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="editor" style="height: 500px; width: 800px">Type in a word like "will" below and press ctrl+space to get "auto completion"</div>
  <div id="commandline" style="position: absolute; bottom: 10px; height: 20px; width: 800px;"></div>
</body>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/master/src/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/master/src/ext-language_tools.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>

</html>
```